# Bootstrap 4 - missing padding in navbar-expand

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have strange problem with padding in navbar which depends of navbar-expand.

For example if I set it to MD I will see this:

[image]

Like you can see Logo and menu button doesn't fit to rest of page. What is wrong in my code?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Logo<!--<img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />--></a>
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu" aria-controls="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
            
            <!-- Grupowanie elementów menu w celu lepszego wyświetlania na urządzeniach moblinych -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                   <li class="nav-item "><a href="/index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                   <li class="nav-item "><a href="/index.html" class="nav-link">Offer</a></li>
                   <li class="nav-item "><a href="/index.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
      </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<main class="container">
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h1>Head</h1>
            <p class="text-justify">Sed suscipit magna nulla, quis aliquam massa placerat nec. Cras ultricies, tortor ut pellentesque finibus, tellus nunc rutrum felis, ac lobortis turpis ligula eu lorem. Maecenas et dolor interdum, tristique lacus non, sollicitudin sapien. Sed eu mollis tellus, ac vestibulum felis. Aliquam eu egestas nibh. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Integer et purus ut mauris tempor ultricies. Phasellus et vulputate erat. Quisque at venenatis eros, sit amet convallis enim. Aenean molestie egestas ipsum, vel malesuada ligula. Curabitur velit dolor, condimentum in pharetra lacinia, ultricies et sem. Phasellus et laoreet sapien. Pellentesque volutpat tortor quam. Maecenas nec ultricies magna.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue in Bootstrap 4.0.0. Here's the issue report in GitHub:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/25654

Here is the workaround:

```
.navbar-expand-md  > .container {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
    .navbar-expand-md  > .container {
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-right: 0;
    }
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/S7P86COCRk

Comment: Thanks for inform me :) I hope they will fix it in 4.1 ;)

For temporary using I wrote simple code:
`/*Fix bugs padding in expand-md in BS4 - IF change breakpoint, you have to change the same in CSS*/
.navbar-expand-md>.container, .navbar-expand-md>.container-fluid {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
    .navbar-expand-md>.container, .navbar-expand-md>.container-fluid {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are using `navbar-expand-md` remove it from your layout and you will have the same container size..

Comment: I can't do this, because it is need for colla[sing menu.